# In Oracle Apex, are there Workspace Items, similar to Application Items or an alternative like workspace global variables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

With Oracle Apex 22.2 or above. Is it possible to create "workspace wide items", similar to [Application Items](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/managing-application-items.html) and [Application Settings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/managing-app-settings.html#GUID-CB12C364-FE65-4C4B-A1EB-3ACCC13188F3)? The requirement is:

- share common variable and static values between applications. We are building a "master application framework", that will be the basis for over 50 applications.
- "workspace wide items" must be accessible via [Substitution Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html). For example the value of page item must be set to the "workspace wide item" value. Similar to the sytnax for application items, example: `&MY_APP_ITEM`.
- Sessions between applications will **not** generally be shared, on some rare occasions they might be. Thus the "Global" feature of Application Items is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute "scope" of application items to make them behave as if they're "workspace items"

*Specify Global if the Oracle APEX session is shared by more than one application and the item's value should be the same for all applications.
Specify Application otherwise (this is the default).*

The downside is that all the items need to be created in each of the applications but it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Koen. I;ve updated the question, thanks for prompting me. Unfortunately the Global scope for Application Items cannot be used as user sessions will not generally be shared between applications.

Comment: There is no such thing as "workspace items". We have a similar setup in our environment and we use a set of application variables in each app.